# jquery selector stops working after load()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, jquery-load

in short, i have a page where the content is being loaded with jquery load(). the problem is when i am trying to select.

```
$('a.selected_class').click(function(e){
 alert('alert');
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

(inside document ready) works on the first page, but on any subsequent pages (that are loaded using $(this).load(url); into a div), the selector stops working.

any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't that it stops working. It is that it only binds `click` handlers to those elements that exist when it runs (on page load).

You can place a [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) handler on the `<div>` that the dynamic ones are loaded into.

```
$('#mydiv').delegate('a.selected_class','click',function(e){
   alert('alert');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

The handler is placed on the `#mydiv` element, and when the `click` event bubbles up to it, it tests to see if the event took place on an element that matches `a.selected_class`.

The `.live()` method does the same thing, but it does it for the *entire* document, so it normally isn't an advisable method to use.

Answer (score 6):

`click()` only will work on elements that exist on the page currently.  Check out [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) and [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate).  With `live`:

```
$('a.selected_class').live("click", function(e){
 alert('alert');
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

As patrick dw mentions, `delegate` is preferred if possible.